# Exercise 6 International Math Competition integration

Tags: functions, definite-integrals, lebesgue-measure

Source: https://www.imc-math.org.uk/imc1995/prob_sol.pdf
I don't understand the first paragraph of the solution of exercise 6 (second day): ,,It is clear that one can add some functions, say $\{g_m\}$, which
satisfy the hypothesis of the problem and the closure of the finite linear
combinations of $\{f_n\} \cup\{g_m\}$ is $L_2[0, 1]$. Therefore without loss of generality
we assume that $\{f_n\}$ generates $L_2[0, 1]$''. Can you expain me more clearly?

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure what level of students this is intended for. The intuition behind what is going on is quite clear and trivial if one thinks of orthonormal bases of $L^2([0,1])$ equipped with the usual inner product $\langle f,g\rangle= \int_{\mathbb{R}} f\bar{g}dx$, e.g. the standard Fourier basis.

The sequence as defined in the solution is an orhonormal system, i.e. it may not be complete. But any collection of linearly independent vectors can be extended to a basis (assuming axiom of choice or something of the sort for infinite dimensional spaces in general) and then one can make sure the basis is orthonormal using Gram-Schmidt when adding each of the new vectors. This is how you can complete with the $g_m$ and crucially maintain the property that the inner products of different functions are $0$.

Comment: Thanks! I understand :)  Why we need to know that $f_n$ create the base?

Comment: Because if you have  a basis, it is complete, i.e. if $\langle g, fn \rangle=0$ for all $f_n$, then $g$ must necessarily be the $0$ function (in the $L^2$ sense).

Comment: Okey, but in solution we take $m\in\mathbb{N}$, but this $m$ must be different than $n_k$? So we don't have all $f_m$.

Comment: That is just a relabeling. The basis extension stuff is to argue that you can assume that the $f_n$s are a basis already.